# Confusion about the notation for the directional derivative and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> For an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable if the function $f$ has a derivative at every point $x_0 \in A$; Then $$Df :A \to \mathcal{L} (\mathbb{R^n,R}), x \mapsto Df(x).$$

I'm a bit confused about all these definitions. What does $Df$ represent here? Apparently it's not the directional derivative I initially tought it was.

Also another definition:

> The differentiability at a point $x_0 \in A$ means that $$f(y)-f(x_0)=Df(x_0)(y-x_0)+||y-x_0||\varepsilon(y-x_0)$$ for all $y\in B^n(x_0, r) \subset A.$

Here again the notation $Df$.

For the directional derivative I've always used the notation $D_uf = \nabla f \cdot u$.

Also I have quite several times used $$f(x+h)-f(x)=\nabla f(x)\cdot h+||h||\varepsilon(h)$$
to show differentiability, but this one uses the directional derivative as $\nabla f(x) \cdot h = D_hf$. Could someone please elaborate on these and why does it seem that there's a bunch of different things representing the same concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator $\mathrm D$ means total derivative or total differential. $\mathrm Df(x)$ is the total differential of a function $f$ at the point $x$. It is a linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ (or more generally $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ if you choose $\mathbb R^m$ as the codomain of $f$), and its defining property is the equation you wrote down yourself:

> $f(y)-f(x_0)=Df(x_0)(y-x_0)+||y-x_0||\varepsilon(y-x_0)$ for all $y\in B^n(x_0, r) \subset A.$

Now if the codomain is $\mathbb R$, like at the start of your post, then we often write $\nabla f(x)$ instead of $\mathrm Df(x)$, but they mean the same thing. The directional derivative $\mathrm D_h f(x)$ is then defined as $\mathrm D_hf(x):=\mathrm D g(0)$, where $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^m,~g(t)=f(x+th)$. It's essentially the derivative of $f$ if we restrict $f$ to a line through $x$ parallel to $h$. It turns out that $\mathrm D_h f(x)=\mathrm Df(x) h=\nabla f(x)h$, which is the equation you mention near the end of your post.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the clarification. I've also seen this similar definition, but instead of $Df(x)$ they had the jacobian, is there any relation to that?

Comment: The Jacobian is just the matrix representation of $\mathrm Df$ with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: And since the Jacobian is a linear transformation(not sure if linear map and linear transformation are synonyms) that implies that $Df$ would also be?

Comment: It's the other way around. $\mathrm Df$ is defined to be a linear map (transformation implies a linear map from a vector space to itself, which $\mathrm Df$ doesn't need to be). And as such, it has a matrix representation. The Jacobian is then defined to be that matrix representation, even though it's often introduced before the formal definition of the differential. Also keep in mind that there is a slight difference between matrices and linear maps. Matrices are just a way to represent linear maps, and there are multiple ways to represent a linear map as a matrix. **continued**

Comment: The Jacobian is just one specific matrix representation of $\mathrm Df$. Namely the one with respect to the standard basis.